# Backreference in RegExp replace function not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my code for string replacing:

```
var input = "player @renish Score";
var matches = input.replace(/@\w*/g,'$1 55');
```

The output is

```
player $1 55 Score
```

I want the output like

```
player @renish 55 Score
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$1` is called a backreference and it will be valid only if there is a valid capturing group.

Quoting MDN's [Grouping and back references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) section,

> **`(x)`**
>
> Matches `x` and remembers the match. These are called *capturing parentheses*.
>
> For example, `/(foo)/` matches and remembers `"foo"` in `"foo bar"`. The matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements `[1], ..., [n]` or from the predefined `RegExp` object's properties `$1, ..., $9`.
>   You need to introduce a capturing group, like this

```
console.log(input.replace(/(@\w*)/g,'$1 55'));
```

Now, we capture the string `@\w*`, and the `$1` will represent the captured string.

---

Alternatively, as per the [ECMA Script 5.1 Specification for `String.prototype.replace`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.11), you can use `$&` to represent the matched string.

> **`$&`**
>
> The matched substring.

So, you can use the code as it is and simply change the replacement pattern to `$&`, like this

```
console.log(input.replace(/@\w*/g,'$& 55'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify what part of your regex is your capturing group, using `()`:

```js
var input = "player @renish Score";
var matches = input.replace(/(@\w*)/g,'$1 55');
alert(matches)
```

Otherwise, the `replace` will literally place `"$1"` into your string, because you haven't specified a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the whole match with `$&` , no need in capturing groups:

```js
var input = "player @renish Score";
alert(input.replace(/@\w*/g,'$& 55'));
```

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> `$&`    Inserts the matched substring.

Mind that adding capturing groups should only be performed when you only need to refer to some subpattern. Additional capturing groups mean additional overhead.